# Javascript replace all string not inside a markdown code block

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, github-flavored-markdown

I want to replace all occurrences of "](test" string with "test](new/test" in javascript but not inside a markdown code block

Example:

````
replace this one ![](test/asdsa.png)


```md
don't replace this
![](test/image1.png)
```

replace this ![](test/asdsasdsds.png)

```
don't replace this
console.log("![](test/blabla.png)");
const testStr = `![](test/image3.gif)`;
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string into array of lines and use a flag to track markdown blocks by checking if line starts with backticks

Map the lines array and then join() to string with `\n` separator

````js
const textReplace = (str, subStr, newSubStr) => {
  let mdBlock = false;

  return str.split('\n').map(str => {
    if (str.trim().startsWith('```')) {
      mdBlock = !mdBlock;
    }
    // return unchanged string inside blocks, or run replace on string
    return mdBlock ? str : str.replace(subStr, newSubStr)
  }).join('\n');
};


const el = document.querySelector('textarea');
el.value = textReplace(el.value, '](test' ,'---REPLACED---' )
````

````html
<textarea style="width:100%; height:250px">
replace this one ![](test/asdsa.png)


```md
don't replace this
![](test/image1.png)
```

replace this ![](test/asdsasdsds.png)

```
don't replace this
console.log("![](test/blabla.png)");
const testStr = `![](test/image3.gif)`;
```
</textarea>
````

Comment: Great & simple solution. I was trying to use regex for this but seems that it is an overkill / make things more complicated. Thanks a lot

Comment: Not hard to do...was first thing I thought about but quickly looked ugly and I'm not great at complex regex